# BI-Publisher 11g - Create Report with differents Datasources

Tags: oracle, bi-publisher

I need to create a report with different datasources. In my data model I already have the different datasources, my problem is that I don´t know how to create a report (template) with that data model.

Please help!!

it would be very helpful

Answer (score 0):

Each BIPublisher report is based on one, and only datasource. BIP provides the ability to mix and merge data from different sources, like SQLS, XMLs or webservices. You will have to do this merging in the [data modeller by creating links](https://docs.oracle.com/middleware/12212/bip/BIPDM/GUID-78F618CB-1A43-438F-9003-69A9E34C70E9.htm#BIPDM252).

Also check [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Z08GtJIGpcQ).

After linking, this datasource will be the source of your report template.

Comment: I understand, I've already tried making links and even then I do not get the information from the other data source in the report. I do not know if it can be done from ms-word with the plugin, but I have problems when installing the plugin, in different forums they say that the best thing is ms-word 2003-2007, I install 2007 but still not allows me to create templates correctly

Please help!